# Can I strip HTML tags in the "Compare Revisions" screen?

Tags: shortcode, html, revisions

I am building a CMS for content editors that have zero tech savvy. They currently use a system called NewsCred that allows them to compare revisions much like how WordPress does when you visit /wp-admin/revision.php?revision=[post_id] however their tool doesn't show shortcodes or HTML tags. Some of them are saying it's a deal breaker because HTML confuses them, so I'm trying to figure out how to hook into this to strip HTML and shortcodes from the revision comparison.

Is this possible? I've looked at wp-admin/revisions.php and the wp_print_revision_templates() function but all it has is some template code called {{{ field.diff }}} and don't know where to look from there.

And before you say it's ridiculous for content editors to be confused by HTML in 2016, I agree and have tried fighting that battle.

Comment: That sounds like an objection for the sake of objection. This can not happen and still be a revision compare tool

Comment: @mark-kaplun Technically yes, but content/phrasing/grammar/spelling is all they care about.